# Converting a chr Column to Date type, and formatting it

Tags: r

I have trouble converting and properly formatting a chr column to a date type in RStudio:

Starting point:

```
> str(conjunta_n)
spec_tbl_df [12,441 × 7] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Id                : num [1:12441] 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 ...
 $ ActivityDay       : chr [1:12441] "4/12/2016" "4/12/2016" "4/12/2016" "4/12/2016" ...
 $ Calories          : num [1:12441] 1985 1985 1985 1985 1985 ...
 $ SleepDay          : chr [1:12441] "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM" "4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM"
```

[Table Output Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbFE8.png)

As you can see, the **ActivityDay** column is a **chr** data type, but when converting it to date type with:

```
conjunta_n$ActivityDay<-as.Date(conjunta_n$ActivityDay)
```

I get:

```
> str(conjunta_n)
spec_tbl_df [12,441 × 7] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Id                : num [1:12441] 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 ...
 $ ActivityDay       : Date[1:12441], format: "0004-12-20" "0004-12-20" "0004-12-20" "0004-12-20" ...
 $ Calories          : num [1:12441] 1985 1985 1985 1985 1985 ...
 $ SleepDay          : chr [1:12441] "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM" "4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM" "4/15/2016 12:00:00 AM"
```

[data type changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnDn7.png)

RStudio assumes that the first number (**ActivityDay** Column) corresponds to the year, and adds 3 zeros to the first number (but the first number is really the month, and the last one the year) ...

I try to fix this by adding format="%d-%m-%Y" (I also tried with dots and commas) to the function:

```
conjunta_n$ActivityDay<-as.Date(conjunta_n$ActivityDay, format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

but I ended up with NA values instead (**ActivityDay** Column):

```
> str(conjunta_n)
spec_tbl_df [12,441 × 7] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Id                : num [1:12441] 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 1.5e+09 ...
 $ ActivityDay       : Date[1:12441], format: NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Calories          : num [1:12441] 1985 1985 1985 1985 1985 ...
 $ SleepDay          : chr [1:12441] "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM" "4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM" "4/15/2016 12:00:00 AM"
```

[NA values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mncY9.png)

I've been trying to find a solution with no success, so I came here to ask for help from the experts!

Please keep in mind I'm new at R so it will be really appreciate it if you try to keep your answers as simple as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Your data shows `"4/12/2016"` with *slashes* between the numbers, why did you try `"%d-%m-%Y"`, with **dashes** in between them? (Try `format="%d/%m/%Y"`.)

Comment: FYI, RStudio is not a language, it is an IDE, and it assumes nothing about the data. **R** is the language, and if you read [`?as.Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html), you'll see what `format=` defaults to.

Comment: No particular reason. I used slashes, commas, and dashes because they were used in the documentation or in the explanations I found on the web when trying to find a solution for it... But I'll give it a try with slashes! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is that you are doing d/m/y when your character format is in m/d/y (the `"4/15/2016 12:00:00 AM"` value in `SleepDay` suggests this, but I may be wrong).

At any rate, you you can do this two ways, with the latter (`lubridate`) being the easiest:

```
df <- data.frame(index = runif(3),
                 ActivityDay = c("4/12/2016","4/13/2016","4/14/2016"))

df$recreate_error <- as.Date(df$ActivityDay) # recreate error

# Base R
df$mdy_base <- as.Date(df$ActivityDay, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

# Lubridate package
library(lubridate)
df$mdy_lubridate <- mdy(df$ActivityDay)
```

Output:

```
#      index ActivityDay   mdy_base mdy_lubridate recreate_error
#1 0.5214453   4/12/2016 2016-04-12    2016-04-12     0004-12-20
#2 0.1210779   4/13/2016 2016-04-13    2016-04-13           <NA>
#3 0.8851842   4/14/2016 2016-04-14    2016-04-14           <NA>
```

Comment: thanks @jpsmith! But how can I apply it to the whole column?

Comment: No problem! That does apply it to the whole column

Comment: Javier, one of the harder things for those new to R need to try to accept: R tends to prefer doing things on a vector as a whole. For instance, `as.Date(df$ActivityDay, format="%m/%d/%Y")` (as jpsmith said) operates on the whole column (a vector) at a time, doing the same thing on each value within. It is generally _significantly faster_ to do things as a vector instead of value-by-value, so the challenge is to learn to use it (and to learn the exceptions, which R has plenty of, unfortunately).